# Перенос ячейки таблицы при изменении ширины окна

Tags: html, css

Собственно как сделать так чтобы когда, условно говоря, страница открывалась с мобильного то одна, последняя в строке ячейка переходила на новую следующую строку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Верстать таблицу при помощи div с использованием display: table и прочего для desktop,  а для мобильных использовать медиа запросы и манипулировать display как необходимо.

Пример таблицы на div:

```css
div {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px dotted white;
}

.table {
    display: table;
    background: #d9edf7;
    border-color: #3a87ad;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
    background: #f2dede;
    border-color: #b94a48;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    background: #fbeed5;
    border-color: #c09853;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Город</div>
    <div class="cell">Посещения</div>
    <div class="cell">Страниц</div>
    <div class="cell">Время</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">СПБ</div>
    <div class="cell">500</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
    <div class="cell">00:08:05</div>
  </div>
</div>
```